# Python, Beautiful Soup and cron

Tags: python, linux, cron, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to scrap a website using Python and Beautiful Soup. The script runs perfectly fine from the terminal with `python update.py`. As the same `update.py` suggests, I want to run this daily. Seems like a job for cron as opposed to manually running it.

However, when I try to run it as a cron job, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/me/documents/blotter/update.py", line 121, in <module>
      getDailyLog(yday.month, yday.day, yday.year)
    File "/home/me/documents/blotter/update.py", line 103, in getDailyLog
      note = cleanNote(cells[7], month, day, year, dispatchNumber)
    File "/home/me/documents/blotter/update.py", line 57, in cleanNote
      rows = detailTable.find_all("tr")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'
```

I understand the error message (detailTable is not a soup object and so doesn't have the attribute `find_all`). If this was the problem, I could debug this but the script runs just fine from the terminal on the exact same URL. This seems to suggest that problem isn't with the script.

The error is coming after I used Beautiful Soup to get the summary table without error. It is trying to get the details table in the function `cleanNote`. This makes me think it isn't a problem between cron and Beautiful Soup in general.

What might cause the program that runs on the command line without hitch to crash in a cron job?

**Edit**: Still not clear why it was crashing earlier today when it was running from the command line at the exact same time without problems but the cron job seems to be executing correctly without error now. I made no changes, just set the job to later in the afternoon and it worked fine.

Comment: same interpreter and package versions in both?

Comment: Are you catching and ignoring errors? `detailTable` shouldn't be `None` unless something went wrong and there should be errors or exceptions along the way with more details.

Comment: Padraic, same everything between the runs.

Comment: tdelaney, I'm not handling any errors/exceptions there right now. I'm puzzled as the same script without any changes fails in cron but works on the command line.

Comment: `detailTable` is `None` when it should be a BS object, so something went wrong earlier in the code. You want to work your way back to what went wrong to diagnose the problem. BS and urllib2 (if that's what you are using) typically raise exceptions when problems hit. Maybe `detailTable` is supposed to be set in an `if` clause somewhere but you didn't handle the `else` as an error so it never got assigned. But the point is, look to where `detailTable` is supposed to be set and go from there.

Comment: Right now you are asking us to guess how `update.py` was implemented and then guess what went wrong.

Comment: tdelaney, I know the question isn't perfectly asked but I wanted to spare a everyone dumping several functions worth of code for this question. It seemed to me that the problem was with the cron environment and not the script since it was working. I'm still not certain why it wasn't working but it is now.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, `cron` jobs are executed in a shell that doesn't source any of your "login" files:  `~/.profile`, `~/.login`, `~/.kshrc`, and so on.

It's impossible to know without seeing the output of `crontab -l` (and your login scripts), but my guess is that your script requires something in your interactive login environment.  The usual suspects include:

- The default `PATH` environment variable is finding a different version of `python` than you use from the command line.
- Your `PYTHONHOME`, `PYTHONPATH`, or `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable contain something you rely on.
- Your interactive shell has `"python"` aliased to something else.
- You've been running the script in a `virtualenv` or `venv`, which is not active when you run the script from `cron`.
- Your script depends on something that happens to be in your current working directory.

To narrow down the suspects list, try running `python -E update.py` on the command line to see what happens when the various `PYTHON*` environment variables are ignored.  You could also try the `-s` and `-S` options --- check the `python` man page for more.  Or call your script from some other directory using its absolute pathname.

If the problem is just one missing environment variable, you can change your `cron` entry to set it explicitly:

```
* * * * * env VAR=something python /path/to/update.py
```

Or for a different interpreter:

```
* * * * * /path/to/python8.e.planks-constant /path/to/update.py
```

For more complicated setup, most people write a front-end shell script that configures the needed environment and *then* runs the script you really wanted:

```
* * * * * /path/to/update.sh
```

...where `update.sh` is full of `cd`, `export`, and maybe `source` statements.

Comment: I previously used the solution you describe (`update.sh` where it gets everything in order) for other tasks but wrote my Python with cron in mind. I didn't use relative paths or other things that might lead to trouble. I'm not sure what the problem was here but it seems to have fixed itself between lunch and now.